# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.9.0.0

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-express

The server is Windows 2008 R2 SP2 with IIS 7.5. I am running a PreReq utility to confirm it is setup prior to installing Infor Approva 10.0.

The utility keeps returning the above error. After some research it seems that error is usually thrown because IIS Express is installed and the wrong reference is being used which is fixed by either uninstalled IIS Express or changing the binding in aspnet.config. However I've confirmed that IIS express is not installed, so I was wondering why this error is being thrown? There aren't any existing references in the aspnet.config or the machine.config files.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` is located in folder `%windir%\System32\inetsrv`. You can find it on your machine and check its version.

I think this issue is caused by a wrong assumption of Approva's PreReq, and you should contact their technical support for assistance.

It is very likely that the vendor misunderstood IIS and IIS Express, and had a wrong reference to MWA set in their product.